# DocuSign Documents That Don't Need to be Signed

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to include documents in my envelopes created via API that do not require signatures, but do require that only certain people see them.

I'm looking for a way to include these documents, keep them restricted to required parties.  Any ideas? I'm still new to DocuSign API, so please let me know what other details I can share to help determine best course of action here.

Also, we are using C# for our APIs

Attempted to do this by having the people I need to see these documents as signers, but without the tags for where to sign and date.  I am getting this error because we have the setting for "document visibility" set for this account, which is a requirement for this process.
*
"Error calling CreateEnvelope: {"errorCode":"ONESIGNALLSIGN_NOT_SATISFIED","message":"Freeform signing is not allowed for your account because it conflicts with other settings, please place signing tabs for each signer."}"*

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!***

Answer (score 1):

For document visibility, each document needs at least on field (tab) placed on it. Whichever recipient the field belongs to will be able to see the document.

Plus, each signer recipient needs at least one tab or you're asking for free form signing, and that's not allowed with doc visibility.

The trick is that the field does not need to be a Sign here field. You could add a read-only (locked) text field. -- With no contents, so it would not be visible at all.

But at least one field per recipient is needed. If a doc has no fields then it is visible to all recipients.

Also, you can use confirmed cc recipients for people who won't sign but you want confirmation that they opened the envelope

See the [docs](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=gbo1643332197980&topicId=eui1578456411411.html&_LANG=enus)

If you have more questions, ask a new stack overflow question